# Book with magic: Soldier [insert number here] ends up with an important girl in a swamp

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book or half the book in middle school, roughly around 2012. I can't remember much about the plot, but the book had a purple cover with a picture of purple leather with golden corner frames and some variation spelling of the word magic as the title.

I know there's a boy who doesn't have an actual name, it's "Soldier [insert number here]", who somehow ends up with a very important girl in a swamp. That's how far I've gotten in the book. I've tried Google, Goodreads and even Yahoo. I know the book is real, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 15):

This is Angie Sage's [*Magyk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magyk), the first book in the Septimus Heap series.

[image: book cover]

Relevant excerpts from the Wikipedia plot summary (the whole thing contains spoilers, obviously) that match your description:

> Marcia whisks Jenna to her apartment in the Wizard Tower, where she can temporarily be kept safe. Marcia also finds a boy, part of the Young Army, buried in the snow and close to death. The boy, called **Boy 412**, is rescued by Marcia and is taken into her apartment to warm up. [...]

> The Hunter, accompanied by his Pack, follows the group, heading for the **Marram Marshes**. [...] The group reaches the Marshes and must navigate through perilous bogs, but eventually reaches a safe cottage belonging to Zelda Heap, Silas' aunt, and a White Witch. Aunt Zelda keeps everyone safe and well-fed throughout the winter.

(emphasis mine)

Jenna is the very important girl (princess). Boy 412 is the Young Army boy soldier who becomes one of the main characters.

---

It's the first book in a series which I continued reading at least up to the fifth book. If you enjoy this one, you could have a fun ride ahead!

Comment: Nothing interesting to say about how I found this: I simply recognised it from the OP's description. A boy whose "name" is Soldier [insert number here] was already a big pointer for me, and all the other details just confirmed it.